# mysql update thousands of rows with one statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that has literally over 200,000 rows and is growing that need to be updated at given time intervals.

I used to do it with a for each loop and it worked until recently. Now I'm getting php timeout issues.

The update is quite simple. It uses a unique id for the row and updates the quantity.

I looked at using CASE but it would seem there is a limit on how many rows could be updated.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: There isn't a limit on how many rows may be updated in a single query; but using a loop is going to be incredibly inefficient

Comment: You'll need to post some code for us to have any chance of providing any help.

Comment: what kind of changes do you need to apply on your data ? Using a for loop for this is only relevant if each one of the 200,000 changes is unique.

Comment: Lesson learned. Never execute a query inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's a stab in the dark.  You mention "update the quantity".  There are a couple angles you could take.

1. In your code, determine how many unique "quantities" you have to update.

   Let's say you have 200K products to update, but stock levels tend to stay in the 0 to 50 range.

   Then you'd have only about 50 SQL statements to make.  They might, however, have rather large concatenated IN statements attached.  The guts of your FOR loop would look something like this:

   ```
   $s = "update myTable set quantity = 10 where id in (124,1215,1232,4444,4532,46789);";
   $r = $db->query( $s );
   ```
2. Another approach would be to have a local copy of the data, and
   submit a delta for only those products whose quantities have
   actually changed since the update.  That is, for all products that
   have increased by 1, concatenate the product IDs, and do:

   ```
   $s="UPDATE myTable SET quantity = (quantity + 1) WHERE id IN (124,1215,1232,4444,4532,46789)";

   $r = $db->query( $s );
   ```

It's not terribly difficult to make these concatenated IN statements.  Say we have $array_of_ids_that_went_up_by_5:

```
$in_statement = "( ".implode(",",$array_of_ids_that_went_up_by_5)." );
```

You might need to rtrim() a comma from the end.

Should be quite a bit more efficient than 200K SQL statements.